# How to reinit component in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have trouble with [datepicker](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker) component. I use it twice. When I choose date in first datepicker and choosen date equal or later than date in second component, in the second component date should be established for a week later.

How I do it:
template

```
<datepicker
    [(ngModel)]="item.updated"
    [expanded]="true"
    [viewFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
    (closed)='compareDates(item)'
></datepicker>
<datepicker
    [(ngModel)]="item.date_end"
    [expanded]="true"
    [viewFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
    (closed)='compareDates(item)'
></datepicker>
```

compareDates - function, where I compare dates)

closed - custom method which I add in datepicker component

```
close() {
    this.opened = false;
    this.closed.emit();
}
```

when item.date_end changes in second component date is not selected in the calendar

I try reinit second component manually

```
<datepicker
    #datepick
    (click)="clicked(datepick, item)"  <-- this
    [(ngModel)]="item.date_end"
    [expanded]="true"
    [viewFormat]="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
    (closed)='compareDates(item)'
></datepicker>
```

function "clicked":

```
clicked(el:DatePickerComponent, item: any){
   el.ngOnChanges();
}
```

In datepicker I change onInit to onChanges
If I call method click on second datepicker component, it works, but if I call method "click" in any other div, "el" - undefined. I need help

updated:

```
compareDates(item:any){
    let startDate = new Date(item.updated).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    let endDate = new Date(item.date_end).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    let currentDate = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); 
    if (startDate < currentDate){
        item.updated = new Date(currentDate);
    }
    if (endDate && startDate >= endDate){
        let newDate = new Date(startDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+7);
        item.date_end = this.getDate(newDate);
    }
}
```

p.s. sorry for my English :)

Comment: Can you add the implementation of your compareDates function

Comment: I update question